# How to Design Multiple Select Option in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-select

I already made a scroll bar on a multiple select option using jquery, my problem is how to design the arrow on css [like this](http://grab.by/kwQC)

This is one is [my work](http://grab.by/kwQ).

I searched a lot on how to do this on css but all i found was different from this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this what you want look like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sNwrs/10/)

Comment: http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Chosen is *super buggy*, I worked with it before but found it annoying because it's lacking a few features that one would expect from a *dropdown replacement*. But, it is great for simple forms.

Comment: @sweetamylase - The only browser I've ever encountered issues with is IE7. And that was 2000+ options. There is [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/), based on Chosen and a *bit* more full-featured. And I think GitHub's web UI uses plugins based on Chosen as well.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I had to work on a web app that wanted to abstract the fact the dropdowns were Chosen, so it was changing the selected value on the actual `<select>` element, and Chosen wasn't picking up on the changes. I wanted to make updates to Chosen, but it's a pain that you have to submit the update to both jQuery and Prototype version. I don't have time to update for both lol....

Comment: hi thanks for the answers guys. but i already take a look on the chosen. i already made a scroll select option, my problem is how to design it. i will try @jhunlio solutions and see if it works